# c# creating tabs within a form

Tags: c#, tabs

So basically my issue is that I have a windows form application that graphs data that is read in. The problem is that if I want to generate two, three or any number of graphs with different data sets at the same time to compare them I'd need to open a new application and use that to create my new graph. What I'm hoping I'd be able to do would be to add in some sort of tab control, so instead of opening a new window each time I want a new graph I could just open a new tab in the same window, and a new instance of my program would open in that new tab. Is this possible? Thanks for any help or advice you have, its much appreciated.

For instance, lets say the user reads in a file on the first tab, and its graph is created. What I would then like to happen would be for a new tab to appear, and when the user clicks over to it, a button is there that allows him to read in another file, and that new files data is then graphed on this tab. Once that happens a third tab would appear that the user could then click on, and he'd then be able to read in a third file, and so on.

Comment: Just a minor comment: if you put your data on different tabs, then it will be actually harder to compare them, as you will only see one at a time. (Of course you still can start multiple instances... :))
Also: is it winforms? Is it WPF? ... How your current UI looks like (in code). Give a little more detail, please. And finally: Yes, it is [possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx).

Comment: true, but lets say I have 10 data sets, sorting through which of the 10 windows I want would be a pain, whereas if there were 10 tabs in one window it would be very easy to click over between the different data sets. Its sort of like having 10 different Browser windows open for different websites, or having 10 tabs in one browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the TabControl from the Toolbox towards the left onto your form, here you can add a graph to each tab etc.

Comment: can I do it for an unkown number of tabs. For instance, lets say the user reads in a file on the first tab, and its graph is created. What I would then like to happen would be for a new tab to appear, and when the user clicks over to it, a button is there that allows him to read in another file, and that new files data is then graphed on this tab. Once that happens a third tab would appear that the user could then click on, and he'd then be able to read in a third file, and so on.

Comment: I believe you add add tabs to the tab control through code, so you could say once the graph is created add a new tab to the tabcontrol for e.g Form1.tabControl1.Controls.Add(ATabItem);

Comment: can I then have that new tab have a fileBrowser button at the same time?

Comment: You can add a button to this tab, that only appears on this tab. That then displays the FileBrowser once clicked, if this is what your after?

Comment: sort of, I'd like it to appear on every new tab, so it would basically be like having X number of windows, each with a file browser button that when clicked, greats a graph in that window, but merging those X number of windows into one window with X tabs, if that makes sense. And to have there always be one extra tab to read in another file if the user wants to.

Comment: Yeah that should do it, but you will need to create the button programmatically also I believe